# How to align 2 containers together

Tags: css, css-float

I am having trouble since changing my container wrapper to auto resize to the users screen.

What I am trying to do is create a form which has data which has a main column and several sub columns per line.

When I try doing any type of float, when I clear it, it clears the toolbars that I have on the right and left of the container.

I hope that you can see from what I'm trying to do with the sample code I made.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
    body {
    background: #fff;
    font-size:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-width:500px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;/*contain inner floats*/
    background:#77F;
}

ul {background:#ccc;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;}
li {list-style-type:none;display:inline;}
.lheader {width:215px;text-align:left;background:#FFF;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="lheader">Left Side 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul><ul>
    <li class="lheader">Left Side 2</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul><ul>
    <li class="lheader">Left Side 3</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
ul {
   background:#ccc;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;
   zoom:1;
}
li {list-style-type:none;}
```

Also note min-width is not supported by all browsers

Comment: display:inline-block; is also not supported by all browsers, you can apply zoom:1; in addition to display:inline-block; as a fix for ie.

Comment: the *display:inline; is for IE's use.